# TypeScript build error for Ionic application using C3/D3 graph library

Tags: typescript, cordova, d3.js, ionic-framework, webpack

I have an Ionic/Cordova application that I am finally (got time to)revisit and add some modifications, so it has been a while since I last built on my mac (I normally develop on windows)

I made my modifications, and it builds fine, for the Android platform, on my Windows machine.

Across to the mac, I then also ran the Android build (I use the mac as the official build machine for both iOS and Android), I am not getting the following error at the webpack stage...

```
            [INFO] Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova

        [08:03:39]  build prod started ... 
        [08:03:39]  clean started ... 
        [08:03:39]  clean finished in 23 ms 
        [08:03:39]  copy started ... 
        [08:03:39]  ngc started ... 
        [08:03:59]  ngc finished in 19.74 s 
        [08:03:59]  preprocess started ... 
        [08:03:59]  deeplinks started ... 
        [08:04:00]  deeplinks finished in 563 ms 
        [08:04:00]  optimization started ... 
        [08:04:01]  copy finished in 21.05 s 
        [08:04:16]  optimization finished in 15.95 s 
        [08:04:16]  preprocess finished in 16.52 s 
        [08:04:16]  webpack started ... 
        Error: ./node_modules/d3-quadtree/src/quadtree.js
        Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
            at isNameOfExportsOrModuleExportsAliasDeclaration (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:23318:47)
            at bindStaticPropertyAssignment (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:23396:17)
            at bindWorker (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:23079:29)
            at bind (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:22974:13)
            at visitNode (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:14662:20)
            at Object.forEachChild (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:14725:21)
            at bindEachChild (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:21771:16)
            at bindChildrenWorker (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:21852:21)
            at bindChildren (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:21746:17)
            at bind (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:22985:21)
        @ ./node_modules/d3-quadtree/src/index.js 1:0-49
        @ ./node_modules/d3/index.js
        @ ./src/pages/performance/performance.ts
        @ ./src/pages/performance/performance.ngfactory.ts
        @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
        @ ./src/app/main.ts
            at new BuildError (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
            at callback (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:119:28)
            at emitRecords.err (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:265:13)
            at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:371:38)
            at emitAssets.err (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:258:10)
            at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:364:12)
            at next (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
            at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
            at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:222:13)
            at Compiler.afterEmit (/Users/Development/dev/build/myapp/trunk/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:361:9)
```

I see down in the call stack the line `node_modules/d3/index.js`. I have had other problems with builds relating to the C3/D3 before, but this one seems different. And it builds fine on my windows machine.

I updates Node (as it was a lot older than on my Windows), but this made no difference.

My environment (running Ionic info) on the mac is as follows...

```
  ionic info

  cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

      @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
      ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.1

  global packages:

      cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

  local packages:

      @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
      Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.3.1 windows 4.4.3
      Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1

  System:

      Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
      ios-deploy        : 1.9.1 
      ios-sim           : 5.0.13 
      Node              : v8.12.0
      npm               : 6.4.1 
      OS                : macOS High Sierra
      Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000 

  Misc:

      backend : legacy
```

My package.json has the following...

```
         "dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
            "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
            "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
            "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
            "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
            "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
            "@ionic-native/app-version": "^3.8.0",
            "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
            "@ionic-native/device": "^3.8.0",
            "@ionic-native/file": "^3.7.0",
            "@ionic-native/network": "^3.8.0",
            "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^3.7.0",
            "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.6.1",
            "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.6.1",
            "@ionic-native/toast": "^3.8.0",
            "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
            "c3": "git://github.com/masayuki0812/c3.git",
            "cordova-android": "latest",
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
            "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.0.0",
            "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
            "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
            "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "git+https://github.com/3spin/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git",
            "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
            "cordova-plugin-ios-disableshaketoedit": "^1.0.0",
            "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.3",
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
            "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git",
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.1.8",
            "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.6.0",
            "cordova-windows": "^5.0.0",
            "cordova-windows-capability-localnetwork": "^0.1.1",
            "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.0",
            "ionic-angular": "3.6.1",
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
            "ionicons": "3.0.0",
            "js-logger": "^1.3.0",
            "jslogger": "^1.0.3",
            "jszip": "^3.1.3",
            "lodash": "^4.17.4",
            "moment": "^2.17.1",
            "moment-duration-format": "^1.3.0",
            "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
            "rxjs": "5.1.1",
            "semaphore-async-await": "^1.3.2",
            "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
            "zone.js": "0.8.10"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
            "@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy": "1.3.0",
            "@types/c3": "^0.4.41",
            "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.54",
            "@types/jszip": "0.0.32",
            "@types/lodash": "^4.14.51",
            "@types/moment-duration-format": "^1.3.1",
            "@types/node": "^7.0.43",
            "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
            "codecov": "^1.0.1",
            "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
            "install": "^0.8.7",
            "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.0",
            "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
            "karma": "^1.7.1",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
            "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
            "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
            "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
            "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
            "protractor": "^5.1.2",
            "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
            "ts-node": "^2.1.2",
            "tslint": "^4.4.2",
            "tslint-eslint-rules": "^3.3.0",
            "typescript": "2.3.0"
        },
```

I know this is a slightly older version of Ionic/Angular, but I was staying with it holding off the updating till I do it to Ionic 4, as I know everything (until this) was working fine. The `2.3.0` of TypeScript is because, at the time, I had another TypeScript compile error with `2.3.3` whick going back to `2.3.0` fixed.

Once again, I do **not** get this on my Windows machine.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is causing this error, or how to track it down, and how I can fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How scarey, my problem was the D, D3, C3 packages in `node_modules` seemed to have changed structure completely (when I did an npm install)!

When I deleted from the mac, and copied these from my windows machine to the mac, all was fine.

Maybe it's because I am using the `"c3": "git://github.com/masayuki0812/c3.git"` rather than just the version. These was some issue way back where I had to target this exact commit.

I have had a number of issues with D3 and TypeScript (ie build issues) so perhaps when I get the time I'll look for another charting library.

Meanwhile, does this means we need to check node_modules into source control!?? I don't want to do that, but I will backup these folders for the time being.

Comment: No, to ensure you get the same version of `c3` from the git repository, you can just append `#` and a commit ID to the URL as described in the [`npm-install` man page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Comment: @MattMcCutchen - Yes I see., thankyou. I actually have not version there at all!. My bad, and good npm. So I should have something like "c3": "git://github.com/masayuki0812/c3.git`#v0.4.17", as 0.4.17 was the version I have in my `node_modules` on my windows machine.